# How do i find created temp table using sqlite in Windows?

Tags: sqlite

I have created Temp Table using below query.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SALESSUMMARY ( product_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, total_sales DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00, avg_unit_price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00, total_units_sold INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)
```

Above query executed. 
Above table does not exist in the database file.
How I find location/path  **"Temp Table / Temp database"** in Windows?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's temporary, so it might not even be saved to disk. What do you need it for?

Comment: I have to find the path of TempTable/Temp Database in Windows.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: What do you need it for? ANSWER: I will find out location/path of created temp table in windows.

Comment: What do you need the location of the temp DB file for?

Comment: What do you need the location of the temp DB file for? ANSWER: For knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible the temp table might not be written to disk at all. From the SQLite [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html):

> These TEMP tables, together with any associated indices, triggers, and
>   views, are collectively stored in a separate temporary database file
>   that is created as soon as the first "CREATE TEMP TABLE" statement is
>   seen.
>
> The temporary files associated with transaction control, namely the
>   rollback journal, master journal, write-ahead log (WAL) files, and
>   shared-memory files, are always written to disk. But the **other kinds
>   of temporary files might be stored in memory only and never written to
>   disk**. Whether or not temporary files other than the rollback,
>   master, and statement journals are written to disk or stored only in
>   memory depends on the SQLITE_TEMP_STORE compile-time parameter, the
>   temp_store pragma, and on the size of the temporary file.

If you don't see the temp file(s) in the same location as the db or in your temp folder (which changes depending on Windows version?), it's likely there is no file, and that SQLite is storing it in memory.

Comment: SQLite calls [GetTempPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I have found out temp file in default Temp Folder(Windows) but these files state are hidden.